# "Hello world" application uses 4 threads in .NET4.0, but 3 in .NET2.0

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

When running the most basic "Hello, World!" application compiled for .NET2.0 you should see 3 threads (Main, GC and Finalizer). However, with a .NET4.0 build that number goes up to 4 with the same basic application. Does anyone know what the extra thread is for?

Comment: What is the app running on? IIS, Cassini etc?

Comment: What kind of app is it? A console one?

Comment: If I create a bare-bones console app, with a single `Console.ReadLine()` within `main`, and debug it, I see 7 threads. You need to create a short-but-complete walkthrough so that others can see what you're seeing (or that will allow you to work out the difference yourself)

Comment: This is a simple console app with nothing more than a Console.Write in the Main() function. 7 threads through the debugger is probably right since the debugger will add its own threads to improve debugger startup. Hopefully, you'll see just 4 if you start with CTRL-F5 instead of F5. If the same program is built in .NET2.0 you should see just 3 threads. I can explain the 3, but don't know where the extra thread comes in when running against .NET4.0

Comment: If I start with CTRL-F5, then attach the debugger, I see two threads. Again, a short-but-complete walkthrough that lets us see what you're seeing would be **rather useful**.

Comment: If you check the threads with Process Explorer you can see the 3 threads vs 4 threads.

Comment: This is what I did: 1 create console app. 2. in Main do Console.Write("Hello, World!"); Console.ReadKey(); 3. Ran via command line. 4. Observer 4 threads through task manager. 5. Since I am using VS2010, the default build is .NET4.0. 6. Changed to .NET2.0 7. Rebuild. 8. Rerun in command line 9. Observed 3 threads in task manager.

Comment: @user1226346 - I'll try to reproduce this - but please, edit your *question* to include this info.

Comment: @user1226346 - I'm trying to reproduce this, but I can't find anywhere in task manager whether I can even get access to thread info.

Comment: Okay, I have finally been able to reproduce this (now I know I'm looking for thread count rather than detailed info). I'm now left with a more difficult issue - it's documenting OS threads - there's no guarantee of OS threads vs managed threads. And we're in a managed runtime - why should we care how it is implemented?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 scenario is same as debugging (F5), if you turn off VS host process. To do it, go to Project Properties -> Debug -> VS host process.

Answer (score 0):

The thread pool keeps idle thread(s) by default **since .NET4** (as [MSDN points it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx)).
I cant find how their number is specified (although you can change it with SetMinThreads), it probably isnt.

This [dotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool-setminthreads) article suggests that it depends also on the number of cores on the machine (which makes sense).

You could test on your machine/specific program to print ThreadPool.GetMinThreads() with both CLRs.